# How to join columns sharing the same name within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, join, duplicates

I'm new to pandas. My df looks like this:

```
  A   A   A   B   B   B
a NaN NaN 2   NaN NaN 5
b NaN 1   NaN 9   NaN NaN
c 3   NaN     NaN 7   NaN
```

How can I get

```
  A   B 
a 2   5
b 1   9 
c 3   7
```

It looks like merge, join are for more than one dataframe. I have also tried

```
df.groupby(by=[A,B], axis=1)
```

but got

```
ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

Comment: Waht about `df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need specify first level with aggregate function like `sum`, `mean`, `first`, `last`...:

```
import pandas as pd

df = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
print (df)
     A    B
a  2.0  5.0
b  1.0  9.0
c  3.0  7.0
```

And if need filter columns by names use subset:

```
df = df[['A','B']].groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
```

If working with index values:

```
df1 = df.T
print (df1)
     a    b    c
A  NaN  NaN  3.0
A  NaN  1.0  NaN
A  2.0  NaN  NaN
B  NaN  9.0  7.0
B  NaN  NaN  NaN
B  5.0  NaN  NaN

df = df1.groupby(level=0).sum()
#default parameter axis=0 should be omit above
#df = df1.groupby(level=0, axis=0).sum()
print (df)
     a    b    c
A  2.0  1.0  3.0
B  5.0  9.0  7.0
```

Comment: Ok, this will do. But my question is: why I have to specify a level? I thought level is only needed if there are multiple levels in axis 1, which is not the case.

Comment: @edge27 - ithink because working with columns names, if working with index is necessary specify it too, `df.T.groupby(level=0).sum()` is same as `df.T.groupby(level=0, axis=0).sum()`. So for columns need `axis=1` for get columns and `level=0` for first level. also I think it is for distinguish if `MultiIndex` in columns, then is possible specify always level like `df = df.groupby(level=1, axis=1).sum()`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using `first`

```
df.groupby(df.columns,axis=1).first()
Out[35]: 
     A    B
a  2.0  5.0
b  1.0  9.0
c  3.0  7.0
```

Comment: Since df.groupby(df.columns,axis=1) is a pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object, I couldn't see how it looks like, so could you explain to me what does .first() do?

Comment: @edge27 it will returen the first not null value of each group

Answer (score 0):

One clean way is to use a list comprehension with `numpy.isfinite`:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

arr = [list(filter(np.isfinite, x)) for x in df.values]

res = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['A', 'B'], index=['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=int)
```

Result:

```
   A  B
a  2  5
b  1  9
c  3  7
```